# Custom "dirty" logic for Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik, react-state

I have an app made with React and Formik. I am trying to add a warning for users to save changes before navigating away. Starting with react-router-dom 5, we could use Prompt. Therefore, my initial code was:

```
const PromptWhenDirty = () => {
  const { dirty, touched } = useFormikContext();
  console.log('touched:', touched);
  return <Prompt when={dirty} message={'Leave without saving changes?'} />;
};
```

and I added one line to my formik based "step wizard" so now it looks like:

```
  <Form>
    <PromptWhenDirty />
    <Step
      current={currentStep}
      values={values}
      onChange={onChange}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      errors={errors}
      isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
    />
  </Form>
```

The Prompt dialog does show up, and it is working correctly. However, for some steps, my `dirty` flag is always set to `true`. I am unsure why exactly. I do utilize `useField` and a bunch of other features. I am assuming that `dirty` possibly somehow set during [some of] my steps' fields initialization.

Further, until I press submit once [-this is a step wizard where data gets resubmitted on each step], touched is always `{}`. Editing fields data does not set it. Once I submit the form for the first time, every field in my form is in `touched` and set to `true`.

I am fine with  dirty just being set inside onChange as:

```
const onChange = (props) => {
  console.log('set dirty here');
  ...
}
```

I understand that I could use the state hook, and set it inside `onChange`. However, I am under the impression that mixing Formik with the state is a bad idea, hence `useField` was added.

Could I override how `dirty` is computed?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: not yet. the state is a bad idea as it causes rerender. leaning towards using var together with values eg `values['prompt'] = true;` together with a context hook - useFormikContext().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended-up doing the below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // initialization is compete, reset `dirty`
  if (mask.value) {
    resetForm({
      values: {
        ...values,
        mask: mask.value,
        croppedImage: croppedImage.value
      }
    });
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [mask.value]);
```

It is not a perfect solution. Changes to the mask don't set dirty and worse reset it. Yet, it is significantly better than before. Plus, the hook is inside one of the steps. Other steps don't have initialization problems and do not require resetting dirty. I tried to hook-up to `onReady` method of my cropper component. However, in conjunction with formik `useField`, I could not easily get it to work.